# Multi-statement line

Tags: algorithm2e

I want multiple statements to appear on the same line. In other words, for certain statements, I do not want a newline after the semicolon.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
$a \leftarrow 1$\;
$b \leftarrow 1$\;
\end{algorithm}
```

How to do that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean like this: `$a \gets 1$; $b \gets 1$\;`?

Comment: Yes, except doing this does not print the 2 statements on the same line.

Comment: It does for me and that means if you want better help, we will need a complete and compilable minimal working example of your code to reproduce your issue, otherwise we cannot help you. (Also, did you note that there is no backslash in front of the first semi-colon, which causes the linebreak in the first place?)

Comment: No I didn't. It works now, thank you.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi I upvoted your questions as they are good, is there any chance you could post your solution here to help future readers please? Would help keep the site clean and help future people with your issue :)

Comment: I can, but the answer has already been given by Markus G. in the comments